# Returns the minimum element in the list t , recursively

Tags: java, list, recursion

I did the following but it's returning wrong and can't seem to find out why, could you guys please assist where the my mistake is or the thing am missing am confused.

```
public static int min(List<Integer> t) {
         int minimum;
           if (t.size() == 1) {
            return t.get(0);
           } else {
               // index -- first index 
                int index = t.get(0);
                List<Integer> u = t.subList(1, t.size());
                minimum = Math.min(index, u.get(0));// index-  the first index

              }
             return minimum;
          }
```

Comment: you didn't called any recursive call form the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create temporary variables. Instead, you should return (if there are fewer than two elements) the first element. Otherwise, return the minimum of the first element and the result of recursively calling with the sublist. Like,

```
public static int min(List<Integer> t) {
    if (t.size() < 2) {
        return t.get(0);
    }
    return Math.min(t.get(0), min(t.subList(1, t.size())));
}
```

**Or**, in Java 8+ and without recursion, you could do something like

```
return t.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).min().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call it recursively, change to:

```
minimum = Math.min(index, min(u));
```

This is the implementation of a definition like *minimumElementOf(t) = minimumOf( head(t) , minimumElementOf(tail(t)) )*